# CallStaticObjectMethod always return null when calling method from C++ using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a JAR library that contains some method I'd like to use for my C++ project. I'm using JNI to call the method. I was able to call a static method and pass the arguments to it with no problem. However, when I tried the same way with a method that returns string from Java, I couldn't get the string return at all.

The Java method:

```
public static String receiveAckMessage() {
    try {
            in.read(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        receivedMessage = new String(buffer);
    return receivedMessage;
}
```

And in the C++ project, I called the Java method with:

```
JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
jclass cls = env->FindClass("SendMessage");
            if (cls == nullptr) {
                printf("ERROR: class not found!\n");
            }
            else {
                jmethodID meth = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "receiveAckMessage", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
                if (meth != nullptr) {
                    jstring strs = (jstring)env->CallStaticObjectMethod(cls, meth);
                    if (strs != NULL) {
                        const char *strReturn = env->GetStringUTFChars(strs, JNI_FALSE);
                        printf("String: %s\n", strReturn);
                   }
                   else printf("Cannot get return value.\n");
                }
                else {
                    printf("Method not found!\n");
                }
            }
```

The `CallStaticObjectMethod` always return NULL at this point and I couldn't get pass it. And I also tried `return "Hello World"` instead of the message from socket, but the result still the same. The String object return from Java code always null.

So my question is how can I get the string return from Java method above?

Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: Put an `ExceptionDescribe` after the failed call and see if it prints anything

Comment: @user2543253: Thank you so much for the suggestion. It turns out that there is a nullpointexception is the Java code. There weren't anything wrong with the C++ call. With the `ExceptionDescribe`, I was able to pinpoint the error and fixed it.

Again, thank you so much.